# Update statement for Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I don't know which the update statement for Stochastic Gradient descent is the right one for the Newton update of the coefficients.

Does it use the sum of the derivatives for ALL variables to update all the  coefficients or is it iterating through each coefficient and using the sum of the derivatives for only that particular variable to update that coefficient?

- On page 120 (pg 139 on pdf) of the Elements of Statistical Learning
  book https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf The Newton
  update statement (4.23) looks like all coefficients are updated with the sum of the
  derivatives of all rows Xi for ALL the variables
- In the update statement in this link http://machinelearningmastery.com/logistic-regression-tutorial-for-machine-learning/
  the coefficients are updated with the sum of the derivatives for
  each that variable and not the sum of the derivatives for all
  variables.
- The update statement on slide # 23, pg 21 for http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~vgogate/ml/2015s/lectures/lr-nb-lec6.pdf
  I read the update statement to say the new coefficient for the given
  variable is the old weight + the derivative of that given variable.